# Which environment/tool to write Spark standalone programs in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, bigdata, apache-spark

I would like to implement a standalone Spark Program in Java. I am using an Amazon cluster to run the application. Since I am a beginner, I would like to know which is the best environment to write Spark programs. Does it also offer debugging functionality?
At the moment I am writing the programs in Eclipse on my local machine and exporting the jars to AWS through Maven-Wagon. The problem is I cannot use the debug.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it in eclipse if you run it in the local mode. Creating a JavaSparkContext like `new JavaSparkContext("local[*]", "my app")` will run your app in the local mode.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just need a short clarification: do I have to install Spark on my local machine?

Comment: I remember that I can directly run a local app in the IDE in Mac or Ubuntu. Not sure about Windows.

Comment: I have a Windows machine. I will try to run it and let you know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install spark on local machine. Just add Spark,scala dependency in your project POM and debug it in eclipse. Pass local in the Confing like below and you can debug your code.

SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("**local**").setAppName(*Application Name*)